# How to declare an array of two dimensional buttons

Tags: android

I want to decalare an two dimensional array of buttons..so can anyone please suggest me how that can be done..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Button[][] buttons = new Button[x][y];
```

Comment: can you please tell me how can i use it for creating an array of buttons in 6 rows and 7 colums..

Comment: Ihave used the follwing code....LinearLayout layoutVertical = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.liVLayout);
       
       for (int i = 0; i <6; i--) 
       {
         for(int j=0;j<7;j++)
            
         {
          Button[][] buttons = new Button[i][j];
          layoutVertical.addView(buttons[i][j], p);
            }
       }

Comment: Why do you want to create buttons dynamically?

Comment: ok.thats fine its done..thanks for your time..

Answer (score 0):

Something like a GridView?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html

You can fix items bidimensionally in a dynamic fashion... Or if you just want something static, use TableLayout

Comment: actually i wanted to create an two dimension array of buttons..i wnat to know how to create it

Comment: What do you mean by "Array"? like so?: Button[] array=new Button[3];
But bidimensionally? Like a Matrix? Why would you want such thing?

Comment: yeh like an two dimensional matrix..Actually i need this for creating an array of buttons..in 6 rows and seven colums..but i am not able to do it so..can u please suggest me

Comment: Button[][] buttons = new Button[6][7];

Comment: the code you posted above is wrong... youre creating an array on each iteration, you must first create it, and then fill it in the nested for's

Comment: but how can i used it in creating an array of buttons of 6 rows and colums..

Comment: I will send u the code ..u please check it

Comment: Button[][] buttons = new Button[6][7];
LinearLayout layoutVertical = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.liVLayout); for (int i = 0; i <6; i++) { for(int j=0;j<7;j++) { layoutVertical.addView(buttons[i][j], p); }

That should work...